# Running Flyway script before Cucumber tests in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, flyway

I inherited the following:

- some modules that build the application as a WAR, with older version of Spring, no Spring Boot
- separate module with Flyway scripts that aren't executed when the main application starts, they are executed during deployment (if I am not mistaking, via maven task)
- separate module with Cucumber tests

I updated the Cucumber module to use Spring Boot (latest version), but I would like to run the Cucumber tests on a clean DB after running the Flyway scripts on it.

Here's the main test class. I can post more code if needed:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/cucumber-context.xml" })
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@CucumberOptions(tags = "not @skip", plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber.html", "json:target/reports/cucumber.json"})
public class CucumberIntegrationTest {
    // ....
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you starting the db as part of spring boot? If so you could use spring boots flyway integration.

Comment: Not currently, but if that works, that might be ok for me. Can you give me more info ?